# How to set-up two objects in one package using MIGx - MODx Revolution

Tags: php, sql, modx

I'm a novice in using MODx Revolution (2.2.8-pl), and I can't really find good enough resources to bring the project I'm currently working on, to a good finish.

To make things short, I'm working on a photo/portfolio website and I need to create a couple of items in the database to store all the projects the photographer has worked on.

I found this wonderful tool called MIGx, which is great and all, but I can't really figure out how to join two tables with it. (only for input)

Basically what I'm trying to do is to add ONE item into the portfolio table, and for each Item, there's a description, date, quote ... and a list of images, each having its own description.

So my guess is that I need two objects in the same package and a link between them.

My XML schema looks something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model package="portfolio" baseClass="xPDOObject" platform="mysql" defaultEngine="MyISAM" phpdoc-package="portfolio" phpdoc-subpackage="model" version="1.1">
    <object class="portfolio_items" table="portfolio" extends="xPDOSimpleObject">
        <field key="item_type" dbtype="varchar" precision="20" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
        <field key="item_date" dbtype="varchar" precision="10" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
        <field key="item_author" dbtype="varchar" precision="30" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
        <field key="item_title" dbtype="varchar" precision="250" phptype="string" null="false" default="" />
        <field key="item_description" dbtype="varchar" precision="500" phptype="string" null="false" default="" />
        <field key="item_text_color" dbtype="varchar" precision="10" phptype="string" null="false" default="grey" />
        <field key="item_sections" dbtype="varchar" precision="100" phptype="string" null="false" default="" />
        <field key="item_keywords" dbtype="varchar" precision="250" phptype="string" null="false" default="" />
        <field key="main_img" dbtype="varchar" precision="100" phptype="string" null="false" default="" />
        <field key="item_img" dbtype="varchar" precision="100" phptype="string" null="false" default="" />
        <field key="published" dbtype="int" precision="1" attributes="unsigned" phptype="integer" null="false" default="0" />
    </object>
    <object class=portfolio_item_section" table="item_content" extends="xPDOSimpleObject">
        <field key="content_id" dbtype="int" precision="10" phptype="integer" null="false" default=""/>
        <field key="content_type" dbtype="varchar" precision="20" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
        <field key="content_title" dbtype="varchar" precision="100" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
        <field key="content_quote" dbtype="varchar" precision="500" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
        <field key="content_color" dbtype="varchar" precision="20" phptype="string" null="false" default="" />
        <field key="content_main" dbtype="varchar" precision="2000" phptype="string" null="false" default="" />
            <field key="content_image" dbtype="varchar" precision="100" phptype="string" null="false" default="grey" />
        <field key="content_tags" dbtype="varchar" precision="10" phptype="string" null="false" default="" />
        <composite alias="contentOwner" class="portfolio_table" local="content_id" foreign="id" cardinality="one" owner="local" />
    </object>
</model>
```

So, what I'm trying to achieve is a link between the two objects and a way to add data through MIGx.

I'm pretty sure that I have to create a template variable and call it in the MIGx formtabs,  which I pretty much did, but I don't know where to find good documentation for MIGx and how to make the damn thing work.

I added an image of what the "Add item to the portfolio" window looks like. Theoretically, when the user clicks on "Add item", he can add as many images with descriptions and tags as he pleases.

[image: Migx interface]

Can you please point out how to config the Template variable so that it can add rows to the second object in the package?

Right now it only displays a cute grid and an input field.

[image: Template variable]

Kind regards, 
Alex

Answer (score 0):

is there a specific reason you need to use custom database tables?

a normal MIGX TV will store all the values within a JSON string in the TV value, which you access through the `getImageList` snippet.

Instead of using the `Form Tabs` and `Grid Columns` input, it's usually easier to create a configuration, this can be done by going to compontents->migx in your manager menu and selecting the MIGX tab, click `Add Item`.

Basically, the `name` field is what you need to type into the `configurations` field of your TV (leave the `grid columns` and `form tabs` blank. The tab labelled `form tabs` will let you set up content entry GUI's and the tab labelled `columns` is for the grid that lists MIGX entries, you don't need to worry about the others.

using this method, you can add a MIGX tv inside of another MIGX tv to end up with items which contain many of another item.

to access nested MIGX values with `getImageList` you basically just pass the value of the nested MIGX value instead of a tvname value ie:

```
[[!getImageList? &value=`[[+nestedMigx]]` &tpl=`outputChunk`]]
```

I know I haven't answered the question you've asked, but I hope this will be helpful

Comment: Thanks Jason, passing the value of a nested MIGX tv to `getImagesList` through the `&value` parameter. I remember reading about it previously but can't see the relevant page in the docs https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/migx